# Как отредактировать модель на вьюхе show другой модели?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

У меня есть модель `Customer`, и связанная с ней через has_many модель `Location`. Это покупатель и его адрес, или адреса. После создания нового покупателя идет редирект на `show` модели `Customer`, т.е. отображаются все только что введенные данные. На вьюхе `show` есть форма для добавления адреса.
На этой же вьюхе отображаются уже введенные адреса, у каждого из которых есть ссылка на редактирование. Мне нужно, что бы когда пользователь нажимал на редактирование адреса, он попадал в ту же вьюху `show` модели `Customer`, но что бы форма ввода адреса была уже заполнена данными того адреса, на который он щелкнул. Вот мой код вьюхи:

```
<p>Информация о клиенте:<br>
<strong><%= @customer.name %></strong><br />
<%= @customer.kind.name %><br />
<%= @customer.adres %><br />
<%= @customer.phone %><br />
<%= @customer.comment %><br />
</p>
<h3>Адреса доставки:</h3>

<% if @locations %>
<ul>
<% @locations.each do |loc| %>
  <li>
    <%= loc.adres %>
    <%= loc.phone %>
    <%= loc.comment %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>

<%= form_for Location.new do |l| %>
  <%= l.text_field :adres %><br>
  <%= l.text_field :phone %><br>
  <%= l.text_field :comment %><br>
  <%= l.text_field :customer_id, type: "hidden", value: @customer.id %><br>
  <%= l.submit "Добавить" %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Форма:

```
<p>Информация о клиенте:<br>
<strong><%= @customer.name %></strong><br />
<%= @customer.kind.name %><br />
<%= @customer.adres %><br />
<%= @customer.phone %><br />
<%= @customer.comment %><br />
</p>
<h3>Адреса доставки:</h3>

<% if @locations %>
<ul>
<% @locations.each do |loc| %>
  <li>
    <%= loc.adres %>
    <%= loc.phone %>
    <%= loc.comment %>
    <%= link_to 'Редактировать', customer_path(@customer, location: loc.id) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @location do |l| %>
  <%= l.text_field :adres %><br>
      <%= l.text_field :phone %><br>
      <%= l.text_field :comment %><br>
      <%= l.text_field :customer_id, type: "hidden", value: @customer.id %>                <br>
      <%= l.submit "Сохранить" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

Экшено show для Customer:

```
def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  unless params[:location].present?
    @location = @customer.locations.build
  else
    @location = @customer.locations.find(params[:location]) 
  end
end
```